# Automatically disable mobile hotspot when no device is connected, using Tasker

Tags: tasker, wifi-tethering

I am trying to create a task which automatically disables mobile hotspot (tethering) when no device is connected. 
I successfully created similar tasks for bluetooth and wifi, however wifi mobile hotspot I seem not to able to get information on how to check if there are clients currently connected or when no client is connected.
I researched a bit, a got a hint that this code :

```
ip neigh show dev wlan0  | grep -i -e reachable -e delay | grep
```

can give information on clients currently connected to hotspot.

This was the output in terminal:

```
u0_a209@hws8701:/ $ su
 -i -e reachable -e delay | grep -o' ..\:..\:..'                              <
unknown option --  usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoPqRSsUVvwxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
        [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
        [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
        [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
        [pattern] [file ...]
[1] + Done                 ip neigh show dev wlan0 |
      Stopped (signal)     grep -i -e reachable -e delay |
      Done (2)             grep -o" ..\\:..\\:.."
2|root@hws8701:/ #
```

however I don’t know how to manipulate this code to get more useful information to create a variable for *zero clients connected*.

Comment: I am also looking for a task to automaticly turn off Wi-Fi tethering when there are no devices connected. Did you manage to get this work properly?

Comment: @JanEnglund I will relook into this and give you feeback :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but i did not find any solution anywhere when i  wanted. So just posting the solution for other enthusiasts.

Ok so i just added a time profile with 5mins interval (choose the time which suits you better) as the trigger.

I added a new task with actions as follows:

**A1:-**

```
    Code > Run Shell

    Command:                     ip neigh show dev wlan0
    Store Output In:             %ipneigh
    Store Errors In:             %ipneigherr
    Continue Task after error:   Yes
```

**A2:-**

```
    Net > Wifi Tether

    Set:                         Off
    IF:
         %ipneigh !~ *REACHABLE*   AND
         %ipneigh !~ *STALE*       AND
         %ipneigh !~ *PROBE*       AND
         %ipneigh !~ *DELAY*
```

**PS**: I don't know the workings of `ip neigh` command. I implemented this by shear trial and error. But It works for me and i am not sure of any bugs yet. Will update with edits if i encounter or anyone comments with any.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a partially working solution to the question.

You will see why I say partial:

**Here is the task for mobile hotspot auto-switch off e.g Hotspot Control**

- A1: Code >> Run Shell >> [Command:`ip -s -s neigh flush all`] *(Clear ARP cache)*
- A2: Task >> Wait [Time: 15 Seconds] *(Wait for connected devices to ping back)*
- A3: Code >> Run Shell >> [Command: `ip neigh show dev wlan0` (Store Output in: `%Clients` Store errors in: `%Error`)]
- A4: Task >> If [Condition : `%Clients` isn't set] *(no device connected)*
- A5: Net >> WiFi Tether >> [Set: Off]
- A6: Task >> Else *(don't turn off mobile hotspot)*
- A7: Task >> Stop
- A8: Variables >> Variable Clear [Name: `%Clients`]
- A9: Task >> End If

[image]

<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Now for the profile/trigger I ran into small problems eventually I decided to try this as beta:

**First**

- State >> Variables >> Variable Value [Conditions: `%Tether` ~ * wifi* ] (If wifi tethering is active)

Entry Task: Hotspot Control

Exit Task : Anonymous task (Set WiFi Tether Off)

**Alternative profile**

- Time >> 5 minutes
- Variable value: `%Error` is set *(i.e Check if no device is connected to hotspot every 5 minutes)*

**Limitations**

- The task works perfectly (i.e it automatically turns off hotspot when no device is connected) but at first instance only.
  Once the `%Clients` variable is populated, subsequent triggers won't work even though I explicity included variable clear function (`Action 8` above)
- I couldn't find a suitable profile but for the meantime the first profile works although buggy sometimes.

Iam still trying to find the best (non-buggy) way of doing this, so I just put this as a partial solution, I am still waiting for better answers therefore 
I will not accept it:)

**Special credits and gratitude**

This work was hugely inspired by [user341464](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/134791/341464), [Squidly](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/113090/squidly) and [Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord) (I had to learn from their tutorials, and make slight adjustments to meet specific needs but its not perfect yet)